# Entering memory adresses into a direct mapping cache

Tags: digital-logic, memory, cpu, cache, mips

I have been given the following problem:
A computer CPU generates the following adresses in 8 bit binary form: 91, B3, 70 etc. The computer has direct mapping cache that can store 64 words and 8 words per line. Find the success rate of this cache.

Now from what i call tell the first step is to understand how many lines we have in total which is 8(64 words/8 words per line). After that we can find how many bits are required for the offset which is log2(8)=3. We can also find how many bits are required for the tag which is 2.

Unfortunately I dont truly understand what all of this means and i cant seem to wrap my head around it.
Can someone help clarify what do the TAG,LINE,OFFSET fields do.
If possible demonistrate with an example by sorting one of those addresses into the memory.